# Difference in rent between a PDA or regular Account?

Tags: anchor, solana-program

Is there a difference between rent that needs to be paid for storing data in a PDA versus Account? Or do they both need to be rent-exempt upon creation, which means two years worth of rent?

Comment: PDAs are accounts so are you referring to "user account" when you say Account?

Comment: I am referring to this piece: https://solanacookbook.com/core-concepts/accounts.html#rent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in the way rent is paid for both PDA and regular accounts.This is because in solana, everything is an account and you will pay the necessary rent correlating to the amount of data that is being stored in the account. So you should always make your account rent-exempt regarless if it's a PDA or a regular Account.

Answer (score 3):

Little known fact: The ['A' in PDA stands for "address"](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/calling-between-programs#program-derived-addresses), not "account" (and even this is a misnomer).  A PDA doesn't have to have an account allocated behind it at all to `invoke_signed` as a signer.

Rent is based purely from an account's data allocation (plus fixed metadata overhead).  The address has no influence

Comment: This sounds like PDAs do not need to pay rent or be rent exempt, and also that @chinepun.sol's answer is incorrect. Is that statement accurate?

Answer (score 2):

All accounts you need to stay alive to store data or lamports need to have enough Sol for rent. That includes PDAs which are also accounts.

I remember that accounts can be not rent-exempted, but I haven't personally tried that and generally not recommended to do.